# Windows phone 7 developer tools with SVN tool

Tags: svn, windows-phone-7

we are a team of around 50 people with window phone developer tools(7.0)  installed on our machines, but we don't have visual studio installed.

Is there any SVN tool available which can be integrated with windows phone developer tools , which can provide services like check in and check out etc.

preferably freeware

thanks and regards.

mohit leekha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the full Visual Studio .NET (Professional/Premium/Utlimate), there are a number of SVN extensions available. Do a search in `Tools :: Extension Manager`

The version of Visual Studio (Express) used by the free Windows Phone Tools, however, does not support extensions so SVN integration won't be possible. I'd recommend using [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), a Windows Explorer shell extension (get it? shell? tortoise?), for your SVN activity.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is good to have all-around, but you have to handle renaming manually.   Try also using the RocketSVN plugin for Visual Studio, it's smart enough to handle the renaming of project files for you.   I use both in my development environments.